# NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[])

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

While debugging my selenium java automation script, I am coming across below exception:

> NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[])

Java compiler compliance level is 1.6.

Comment: Please provide full stack trace. Also are you using `maven` by any chance?

Comment: hi, good to have some info.. code where getting this issue.. are using JUNIT..etc